# ListView inside tab is not filling height?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-tabhost

I'm using TabHost and inside of one tab, I inserted ListView. I set all height's to fill_parent. But it doesn't show full list, but only part of it. What to do to make tab contents fill screen by height?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bkg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientrounded"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/taxisign" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taxiprofiletitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/phonenumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loadFeedbacks"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFF0000" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="#FF000000"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    <TextView
                        android:tag="tab0"
                        android:text="Инфо"
                        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:tag="tab1"
                        android:text="Отзывы"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:tag="tab2"
                        android:text="Тарифы"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        />
                </TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/profile_info"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Info" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView android:text="Добавить"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            </TextView>
                            <ImageButton 
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/reviewslist"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                        </ListView>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/tariffslist"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1" >
                        </ListView>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your very first `LinearLayout` change the `layout_height="match_parent"`. Also, `fill_parent` has been deprecated since API 8 and replaced with `match_parent` so that is what you should be using instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have used wrap content for your listView height. You should always use height as match_parent/fill_parent. I guess your problem is here

```
                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/reviewslist"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </ListView>
```

change it to:

```
                     <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/reviewslist"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </ListView>
```

Adding to that, this layout seems to be innefcient. Listviews inside scrollviews are not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem while quickly viewing the XML file that the parent of your TabHost (LinearLayout) is 'wrap_content' so I am not sure that you are getting all the parents.  I do desire a better UI interface for building visuals through Eclipse.  Not too happy to work out issues like this when they come up.  And they can come up frequently.  Usually it involves some trial and error to get things looking the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll Layout was unnecessary, removing it, made code to work

Comment: I have this problem but need scrollview to scroll all page!